# Using Awk with escape characters inside a Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, escaping

I'm working on a shell script (using Bash) for Linux systems.

As part of this script I'm using awk to get the percentage of packets dropped from a ping request. This works fine when executed from the terminal shown below:

```
test=`ping gnu.org -c10 | tail -2`; echo $test | awk '{printf $6 "\b"}'
```

This gets the percentage of packets dropped and echos it using the backspace escape character to show just "0" rather tan "0%" - this is as the value is used later on as an integer value.

Inside the script, the code looks like this:

```
#Pings the gateway ten times and stores the result
local pingResults=`ping -c10 $gateway | tail -2`

#Uses awk to get the percentage of packets lost using \b to remove the %
local packetsLost=`echo $pingResults | awk '{printf $6 "\b"}'`
```

I return the value from packetsLost and echo it and it gives "0%", totally ignoring the \b

Could somebody please explain why this is happening inside the shell script and how I can remedy this?

I understand there are alternatives such as using cut but I'd like to keep the line as simple and efficient as possible.

Comment: Is the terminal's shell the same as the script's?

Comment: Yes, bash is used for both

Comment: Why not just `gsub` the `%` character off in awk instead of playing printing escape tricks?

Comment: Try `printf("%s", substr($6, 1, length($6)-1))`.

Comment: I felt like Awk was the cleanest and simplest way to achieve what I needed.

Comment: For us to help you write a script to parse the output of ping, you need to provide a sample of the output of ping and the desired output of the command you are trying to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG! Parsing human-readable string basing on word counting is completely unmaintainable (‘write-only’) and unpredictable. Try to avoid it. It’s quite simple actually:

```
$ ping -q gnu.org -c10 |\
     gawk '{ if (match ($0, /([[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+)?)% packet loss/, a)) print a[1]; }'
0
```

`a[1]` here corresponds to the first `()` group in the regexp.

P. S. When you parsing human-readable output it is necessary to ensure that locale (i. e. language) is the same that you expected while scripting, so in actual code `ping` call should look like:

```
local pingResults=$(LANG=C ping -q -c10 "$gateway")
```

(Even if it’s seems that `iputils-ping` in particular does not have any translations.)

Comment: Thank you! This is an excellent answer. I haven't worked very much with using ping programatically so I overlooked the quiet option.

Comment: This only matches numbers after the decimal.  e.g. `99.9% packet loss` would match `9`.

Comment: If you're concerned about locale you should use `[[:digit:]]` instead of `[0-9]`. Also, instead of putting the condition inside the action part, just put it in the condition part: `gawk 'match ($0, /([0-9]+)% packet loss/, a) {print a[1]}'`.

Comment: @JohnB Where did you read that `ping` rounds percentages up to tenths and not to integers. I’ve done some test and got this: `145 packets transmitted, 127 received, 12% packet loss, time 144676ms` while (145 − 127) / 145 ≈ 12.4 %.

Comment: @DimitryAlexandrov Try this on OS X and you'll see.

Comment: @JohnB OK, fixed then.

Comment: @EdMorton As for `[[:digit:]]` – why not, but do you know any real locale, where `[0-9]` contains something except `[0123456789]`?

Comment: @EdMorton As for contracted if-statement notation, that’s just the matter of readability. Full one should be more clear to people who are not familiar with AWK.

Comment: I can not name a locale where `[0-9]` differs from `[:digit:]`, nor can I name a locale where `[a-z]` differs from `[:lower:]` but I have no reason to think they don't exist given someone put effort into creating those character classes. The awk language is a series of `<condition> { <action> }` statements. Not learning that hampers the ability to use awk effectively, like sticking with procedural programming when moving from C to C++ instead of learning the more efficient paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

Check the next:

```
echo 1x 2x 3x 4x 5x 6x 7x | awk '{printf $6 "\b"}' | od -cb
```

you will get the next output:

```
0000000    6   x  \b                                                    
          066 170 010
```

So, when you run the

```
echo 1x 2x 3x 4x 5x 6x 7x | awk '{printf $6 "\b"}'
```

you got printed:

- character 6
- character x
- character backspace (what causes the character remove in the TERMINAL)

Now run:

```
aaa=$(echo 1x 2x 3x 4x 5x 6x 7x | awk '{printf $6 "\b"}')
```

store the result to `aaa`, and show its content:

```
echo $aaa | od -bc

0000000   066 170 010 012                                                
           6   x  \b  \n
```

When want identical result, use:

```
echo -n $aaa
```

so in summary, use:

```
local packetsLost=`echo $pingResults | awk '{printf $6 "\b"}'`
echo -n $packetLost
```

Comment: As I'm using functions, echo works as return. The idea is to gather various data and at the end it will be placed into a large formatted string for output.

I have attempted what you suggest but it still gives 0%, 100%, etc.

Comment: @Kervate in this case, you need remove the `%` from the output. (the `\b` doesnt remove it - as you can see it in the dump.)

Answer (score 0):

`awk '{sub(/%/, "", $6); printf $6}`
or
`awk '{print substr($6, 1, length($6) - 1)}'`